# How to change single material color of GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to change color of object's child color. So, this child has 3 materials, i need to change only one material's color.

[image: Screen1]

On this image you can see whole the object. In it has child "default" with 3 materials. I need to change Blue to red in script. I tried to make this using:

```
ramps[stageCount].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
```

But this script changes White color:

[image: Screen2]

How to get "Материал.2"?

Comment: You are selecting the material index 0 which is pointing to Материал.5. See your materials list, element 2 is the one you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [`Renderer.material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) property which always points to the very first used material.

> Returns the first instantiated Material assigned to the renderer.

If you checkout the `MeshRenderer` -> `Materials` you can see that the first `Element 0` is the `Материал.5` which is changed by your code.

---

The one you want, however, `Материал.2` is the third of your multiple materials at `Element 2` so access it via [`Renderer.materials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html)

> Returns all the instantiated materials of this object.
>
> This is an array of all materials used by the renderer.

and access the index you want, in your case `2`

```
...GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[2].color = Color.red;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!